# Django Machina - display post times in local timezone

Tags: django

I am using django-machina as a forum. I want post times in the forums to be displayed to users in their local times. I have TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' and USE_TZ = True in my settings.py file. I have also installed "pytz." The times are currently displayed in UTC time.

I have attempted to use the following in a template:

```
 <small>{{ node.last_post.created | localtime }}</small>
```

However this has no effect on the display times.

I put this in the template as a test:

```
{% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}
        {{ TIME_ZONE }}
```

and it displays "UTC"

How can I get the times to display in the user's local time zone?